# Angular js to disable directives based on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having a form page which is used for both add and edit form . So at the time of adding data into form , i need to check input data is duplicated or not, so i created a directive which will check with the data base weather data is existed or not.

```
<input name="divId" type="text" class="form-control fL w250"   ng-model="divisionData.DivisionID"  ng-disabled="Disabled()" unique-divid required /></div>
```

at the time of adding new data its works fine . but at the time of edit also using the same form so the unique-divid directive is running. I don't want this to happen in edit page

```
.directive('uniqueDivid', function($http) {
  var toId;
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) { 
     scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(value) {
        if(toId) clearTimeout(toId);
        toId = setTimeout(function(){
          console.log(value);
            $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'http://testurl',
            data    : $.param({'DivisionID' : value}), 
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
        })
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    ctrl.$setValidity('uniqueDivid', true);
                }else if(data.status == 'fail'){
                    ctrl.$setValidity('uniqueDivid', false);
                }
                if (!data.success) {
                } else {
                }
            });


        }, 200);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Please suggest a solution either disable the directive or stop the scope.$watch function at the time of edit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add additional attribute to the input field indicating type of form action (create/edit) it is serving?

For example:

```
<input name="divId" type="text" class="form-control fL w250" ng-model="divisionData.DivisionID" ng-disabled="Disabled()" unique-divid form-action="edit" required />
```

If action type matches the one you want to ignore, just return from linking function.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) { 
  if (attr.formAction === "edit") return;
  ..
}
```

In case you do not want to modify template, what is the indication in controller or scope that could be used to distinguish between new and existing `divisionData`? You could use that property as a flag to return from the `unique-divid` directive:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) { 
  if (!scope.divisionData.isNew) return;
  ..
}
```